# App crashes on device but not in simulator pushing an UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, push

This is the first time I write here but I have a problem that cannot handle :(...

The problem comes when I push an UITableView after push a cell in another table, if I create a general UITableViewController and push it, works, but if I redefine the class with all the necessary methods doesn´t work.

I´ve implemented this before in other code and it works, but now, after updating to Xcode 4.5, doesn´t work...

This is the source code of the view I want to push:

```
@interface ECDetailSettingsTableView ()

@end

@implementation ECDetailSettingsTableView

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ECDetailSettingsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ECDetailSettingsCell"];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

And this is the code that push the tableview:

```
/********************* Pushing View *********************/
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated: YES];

_themeTable = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ECDetailSettingsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_themeTable animated:YES];
```

PD: Thanks for all, and sorry if i´ve made gramatical mistakes :).

Comment: What's the error? Anything helpful from the stack trace? There is no way to help without more details.

Comment: The problem is that in simulator works perfectly, but when I run on iPod the app crashes and I cannot see the stack trace because Xcode cannot handle the process :(.

Comment: Does your iPad have iOS6 installed? You have iOS6 specific code above. It will crash on an iOS5 device. This line:     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: But it´s the same code that I´ve got implemented in other zone :S. I´ve got iOS5 installed on iPod. If delete that line the error still appears...

Answer (score 1):

maybe if you use `segue` in storyboard this generete an error, because this only work with iOS 6.

Comment: I have not used a segue, I´ve pushed it manually like other times, but now doesn´t work :(.

Comment: well using Segues was my problem, I deploy for IOS 5.1 . I use XCode 4.4 and IOS 6 simulator. So with segues app works in IOS6 but not on IOS5. thanks